# Schedule Push notification on Parse

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code, back4app

I was wondering if Schedule Push is available on Parse Server? (I'm using Back4App)

Here is my cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("pushMultiple",async (request) => {  
    //Getting Current Date instance
    var d = new Date();
    //Where I live Current Hour is 14, so setting it to 15
    d.setHours(15);     
    //Sending push to a specific device
    return Parse.Push.send({
            push_time: d,
            channels: [ "t1g.com"],
            data: {alert: "The Giants won against the Mets 2-3."}   
            },{ useMasterKey: true });
});
```

But the code does not seem to be working. The push is sent out immediately.

And if it's not possible, please let me know how I can schedule push using a Cloud Job. A code snippet would be very helpful. Also will the Cloud Job stop running after it has completed sending the push?

Comment: Share your codes instead of pictures!

Comment: okay , updated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using setTimeout() to Schedule pushes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61181249/using-settimeout-to-schedule-pushes)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) document setHours method doesnt add your value to your date but just replace it.

Try this:

```
var extraTime = 1000*60*60*15; //15 hours
var currentDate = new Date();
//since date object is just number we can add our extra time to our date.
var pushDate = currentDate + extraTime; //push date is 15 hours later than now

return Parse.Push.send({
            push_time: pushDate,
            channels: [ "t1g.com"],
            data: {alert: "The Giants won against the Mets 2-3."}   
            },{ useMasterKey: true });
```

Edit: Parse docs says push_time is not supported yet. 
https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#push-notifications

Docs can be outdated or if you are using back4app, they may be implemented this feature to their servers.

Comment: Nope , does not work. set extraTime = 60000(60sec) later , push gets sent immediately

Comment: I believe @UzaySan is right about Scheduled Push not being available. There is an open PR for it - https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/pull/6079.

Comment: Yes it is not supported but I found a work around, please have a look at the updated question.

Comment: @UzaySan 
You can edit out the code in the answer , it might confuse people.